# Where to use API Connect standalone and DataPower

Tags: api, api-gateway, ibm-datapower, apiconnect

I have been using DataPower and APIC both for some time.However currently I am trying to find out where I can use APIC as standalone not involving DataPower .Are there any use case where APIC scores much more than the DataPower or vice versa

I also got some point like DataPower has got issues with OIDC  and APIC is good enough .However the DataPower Gateway v7.7.0.0 and above has that capability.

Please can some help with use case here

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

DataPower is an integral part of API Connect. There is no API gateway without it. So, if you need a gateway, then you cannot use API Connect in a "standalone" fashion.